# logstash grok - how to do conditional pattern matching?

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I have these three log lines in the same log file:

```
INFO [2015-08-27 18:46:14,279] ({qtp243745864-44} NotebookServer.java[onMessage]:101) - RECEIVE << RUN_PARAGRAPH
INFO [2015-08-27 18:46:14,322] ({qtp243745864-44} NotebookServer.java[broadcast]:253) - SEND >> NOTE
INFO [2015-08-27 18:46:16,809] ({pool-1-thread-2} RemoteInterpreter.java[init]:144) - Create remote interpreter org.apache.zeppelin.markdown.Markdown
```

I want to pars them using grok but failing to get the right fields:
1) how to pars the data within the brackets?
2) the last part of the log line is either (CMD direction cmd_data) or (cmd info)
in the example:

```
cmd=Receive or SEND
cmd_direction=<< or >>
cmd_data=RUN_PARAGRAPH or NOTE
```

But the last line is CMD info which does not correspond to the same format.

I am trying to find the right rule that will match the first and second but not the third.
end result should be or (cmd + cmd_data) or (cmd_info) fields
Any help?

Answer (score 12):

Logstash has conditionals in the config file, so you can conditionally match things.

For example:

```
if ([mesage] =~ /(RECEIVE|SEND)/) {
   grok {
      // do your grok here
   }
} else if ([message] =~ /RemoteInterpreter/) {
   grok {
      // do some other grok here
   }
}
```

If you need help with what those `grok`s should be, try using the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Can this be done on a regex? e.g. if ([mesage] =~ /(^\S+ << ^\S+ | ^\S+ >> ^\S+)

Comment: you can use a regex with the if... but the `^` placement is wrong -- its the anchor for start of message.  So you'd want something like `(\S+ (<<|>>) \S+)`

Comment: Thanks! Will test it soon 

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem ...

**It helped me:**

```
if ("SEND" in [message]) {
   grok {
      // do your grok here
   }
}
```